# Octave function terminates inexplicably

Tags: sublimetext2, octave

I am implementing an interpolating function using Octave, and I have the following in a Sublime text file:

```
function root = HermiteInterp(x, y, yp)
Q = zeros(2*length(x), 2*length(x));
disp(Q);
z = zeros(1, 2*length(x));
new_y = zeros(1, 2*length(x));
for i = 1:length(x)
    z((2*i)-1) = x(i);
    z(2*i) = x(i);
    new_y((2*i)-1) = y(i);
    new_y(2*i) = y(i);
    y_prime(2*i) = yp(i);
end

y_transpose = transpose(new_y);
disp(y_transpose);
yp_transpose = transpose(y_prime);
append_to_Q = [y_transpose, Q];
disp('test1');
disp('test2');
```

Yet the function never makes it to the display statement. What's causing this?

Comment: Please add also the call and your data. Create a minimalistic example which can be run.

Comment: actually it turns out I'm just a moron and didn't realize you used the arrow keys to scroll down. this question is now a non-issue

Comment: Can you close the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow keys to scroll up and down the GUI.